# When moving JSX content to separate file it doesn't render properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-framework-7

Let say I have this:

```
// Parent component:

export default function() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Toolbar slot="fixed" bottom>
        This will be fixed to bottom of page
        {order.name}
      </Toolbar>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
```

I want to make the parent component with the least of code possible - shared
into small cuts, so the toolbar will be in a child component so it will be 
looking just like this:

```
// Parent component: 

export default function() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <MyAwesomeToolbar order={order} />
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}

// MyAwesomeComponent: 

export default function(self) {
  let { order } = self.props
  return (
    <Toolbar slot="fixed" bottom>
      This will be fixed to bottom of page
      {order.name}
    </Toolbar>
  )
}
```

In the first example - when the toolbar is actually hard coded in the parent component, 
everything works good - the toolbar lays in the bottom of the page. 
But when doing it the second way, the toolbar lays just not in the bottom but 
float in the middle of the page without the fixed attribute as well.

I have tried to make a component using class, or just a simple render file (.JSX). 
Both didn't work.

How to render child component with the same properties and styles as it was layed in the parent?

Comment: Try to put this code into an online code sandbox - it will make it easier to pinpoint the issue, which might be in the imports for example

Comment: Are you sure this code work? because in the child component you are referring to the props as `self`, and trying to access `self.props.order`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it work if you move the `<React.Fragment />`?

```
// Parent component: 

export default function() {
  return (
      <MyAwesomeToolbar order={order} />
  );
}

// MyAwesomeComponent: 

export default function(self) {
  let { order } = self.props;
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Toolbar slot="fixed" bottom>
        This will be fixed to bottom of page
        {order.name}
      </Toolbar>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Comment: Yes it works. But I need to render multiple blocks, how to do so without the React Fragment?

Comment: Multiple blocks? I'm not sure what you are asking. You want multiple `<MyAwesomeToolbars />`?

Comment: The toolbar comes with more blocks. So I cant render it without the `<React.Fragment>` block

Comment: Are you saying that you basically want `<React.Fragment />` to be used inside of toolbar for some other child component?

Comment: Yes. And problem solved I am using Framework7 and in Framework7 I should use slot="fixed" in the parent child like to: `<MyAwesomeToolbar order={order} slot="fixed" />` (not only in the toolbar page itself)